# Django delete an object without cascading to ManyToMany relationships

Tags: python, sql, database, django

Here's the situation:

```
class Party(models.Model):
    hosts = ManyToManyField("User")
```

Now let's say I have a party `p`. I want to delete `p` (i.e. through `p.delete()`) without deleting all its hosts. How do I do this? If I add the option `on_delete` to hosts, django does not recognize it.

Comment: If you delete `p`, its `hosts` won't be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The cascading delete feature applies to ForeignKey relations, since the model that holds the ForeignKey likely has state and behavior that depend on the relation. To avoid cascading delete in that situation, for some object foo, you would have to iterate over all of foo's related objects, ensuring that all of them have

```
null=True
```

for foo, then you would have to set

```
foo=None
```

for every such related object, and then you could call

```
foo.delete()
```

without foo's related objects being deleted.

But none of that applies in your case, since you have a ManyToMany field. Cascading delete doesn't make sense for a many-to-many relation, since no one object is tightly coupled to another, as with ForeignKey.

Comment: Hm, but doing `p.delete()` also deletes all users in the ManyToMany relationship. I 'solved' this already, btw, by just removing all users from the relationship and removing the party from all relevant user's party_sets. Even after doing that, and doing `p.delete()`, all users are deleted... so I am simply unlinking the relationship and keeping the party in the database and not deleting the party.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. According to the Django docs, "When Django deletes an object, by default it emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE – in other words, any objects which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be deleted along with it."

Comment: @wbr what about OneToOne relationships, does Django apply on cascade delete to them?